# JavaScript challenge stuck? or incorrect?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I would greatly appreciate your help.  So far what I have is..

**Task**

- Declare these local variables and make them equal to the appropriate information, firstName, LastName, linkedIn, phone, city.
- Using string concatenation, make a local variable fullName equal to your first and last names separated by a space.
- Make a local variable linkedIn, a string which is a link to your LinkedIn profile.
- Make a local variable info which is an array containing your fullName, linkedIn, phone, and city variables, in that order.
- Make a local variable education which is an array containing the name of your college/university, field of study, an integer which is your year of (anticipated) graduation. Make sure it's in that order.
- Define a function createApp which takes your info and education as arguments in that order. This should return an object containing 2 keys. The key names must be the same as your variable names. Set the values of these keys to the corresponding arguments.

So far this is what I have but seems incorrect when I try it on the simulator.

```
var firstName = “Santi”;

var lastName = “Valle”;

var fullName = firstName +" "+ lastName;

var linkedIn = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/santi-valle-889827120";

var phone = “(415)619-4985"
var city = “palo alto”

var info = [fullName, linkedIn, phone, city]

var education = [‘UCI’, 'accounting','2013’]



function createApp(info,education){
  var obj = {}

     strArr = ['info','education'],
      myArray = [info, education];

      for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        obj[strArr[i]] = myArray[i];
      }

   console.log(obj);

}
```

Comment: `education[2]` is `'2013'`, which is a string, but the prompt requested an integer

Comment: You have fancy quotes, that is an error.

Comment: Get rid of the `“` and `”` and replace them with normal quotes - `"`.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? It looks like you're using "smart quotes" (like what you get when using WordPad) and it's causing some syntax errors. You need to use normal double or single quotes. `"` or `'`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pesky issue where not all quotes are created equal.  This: `“`, even though it looks like a quote, is not actually a quote the JavaScript interpreter can understand.  It needs to be this: `"` instead. This normally happens when you copy and paste from something like word.  It uses a different character for a quote that "looks better."  The problem is that JavaScript doesn't know how to  translate between the two different quotes and interprets it as a different character.  The easiest way to solve this issue is to first copy the code into something like notepad, and that will change all the "fancy quotes" into normal ones.  You then can copy it into your editor, jsfiddle, etc.  Single quotes suffer from the same issue as well and you had it around things like: `‘UCI’`

```
var firstName = "Santi";

var lastName = "Valle";

var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

var linkedIn = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/santi-valle-889827120";

var phone = "(415)619-4985"
var city = "palo alto"

var info = [fullName, linkedIn, phone, city]

var education = ['UCI', 'accounting','2013']



function createApp(info,education) {
  var obj = {}

     strArr = ['info','education'],
      myArray = [info, education];

      for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        obj[strArr[i]] = myArray[i];
      }

   console.log(obj);

}


createApp(info, education)
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kgk3y5ff/

A note about this:

> Make a local variable education which is an array containing the name
>   of your college/university, field of study, an integer which is your
>   year of (anticipated) graduation. Make sure it's in that order.

Technically speaking, there is no integer type in JavaScript.  The only number type is....number.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

You technically have it as a string by doing: '2013', and you can make it a number by removing the single quotes.  (Personally I don't think this should make any difference, because you're really not using it as a number.  You're not performing a numerical operation on it like add, subtract, etc., but if that is really what is called for, you might want to change it.)